# Where to put the code inside a fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have this fragment:

```
public class Fragment_PV extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      //option 2

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pv, container, false);
//option 1

}
//option 3          
  }
```

Now i want to do a fairly significant amount of math when somebody pushes a button in the layout that goes with this fragment. As it stands, the layout loads fine but of course nothing happens.

When i put the code where option 1 is, eclipse says that the code is "unreachable"

When I put the code where option 2 is, there are no compile errors but the app crashes when the fragment is loaded saying it encounters an error in the oncreateview method

When I put the code where option 3 is, it tells me that the parentheses {} are set wrong and it should be remodeled that it looks like option 1 ...

help please :)

p.s. the code i was testing to put in,just to see if it was working is this:

```
Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error!", 5000);
                errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                errormsg.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in `onActivityCreated`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Your code here

    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error!", 5000); 
    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
    errormsg.show(); 

}
```